# Compaq 610 fan is constantly on and noisy, base is fairly hot too

Tags: fan, compaq-laptop

The fans on both of my HP Compaq 610s are constantly on and the base is fairly hot and I don't know if this is standard issue. HP assures me that this is unusual and that I should return them as DOA.

Because both laptops have this problem, I'm thinking that this might be a design flaw rather than a one-off problem.

I've updated the BIOS and using their recommended power settings.

Am I missing something? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes and next steps:

- Dust in the system, preventing heat dissipation.

  - Turn off the laptop and use compressed air to try to clear the dust.
- A process is keeping the CPU at or near full use.  If your CPU has power management it will be running hotter than usual.

  - Use a program like Task Manager or Process Explorer to determine what program is causing excessive use of the CPU.
- A process is using the GPU heavily causing it to produce heat.

  - I am currently not sure how to determine the program that may be causing this issue.